# Visual studio update model from data base Issue

Tags: c#, git, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, ado.net

```
i was facing a issue  while trying to add a new Store Procedure from database .  update model from data base is showing extra line changes in all Store Procedure and showing in "Include Changes " in Visual studio . I am using Visual Studio 2015 , trying to add newly created store Procedure in Entity . any help will be appreciable ,it making me in trouble a lot .[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

this screen getting after update from model .
[image]
this screen getting after comparing changes , 
[image]

please look the my setting that i am getting after run "git config -l --show-origin"[image]

Comment: I have fallowed these steps :-


a. Creating Store Procedure.

b. Trying tool  option " update model from data base".

c. checked Store Procedure for updating .

d. it showing all store procedure "Include Changes "  section in Visual studio .

e. i was trying to add single store procedure but showing now all changed .

f. when i am comparing changes only showing one extra line with each Store Procedure . 

Let me know ,if more clarification needed .

Comment: Did you check as discusses your git config -l for any core.autocrlf true?

Comment: yes ,everything is fine there . 
one core.autocrlf : true , below second  core.autocrlf : false ,so i think last one overriding first one .

How i can see you complete setting options .

Comment: As I said: git config -l --show-origin

Comment: core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/mingw32/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.required=true

Comment: mergetool.prompt=true
mergetool.vsdiffmerge.cmd="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\vsdiffmerge.exe" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$MERGED" //m
mergetool.vsdiffmerge.trustexitcode=true
mergetool.vsdiffmerge.keepbackup=false
core.autocrlf=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true

Comment: @VonC look above setting showing by running "git config -l "

Comment: You can edit your question with this output: that will be easier to read.

Comment: @VonC i have Edited my question and attached 3 three screen shot .


1 , issue i am getting after taking update from model from Visual studio .

2. After making compare changes , showing new line at my end , you can see screen now .


3. configuration options  that i am getting after run "git config -l --show-origin".


Let me know , if more clarity needed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was facing a issue while trying to add a new Store Procedure from database:
>   update model from data base is showing extra line changes in all Store Procedure and showing in "Include Changes " in Visual studio .

Those extra lines are simply empty lines added between method declarations.
They have nothing to do with core.autocrlf and eol (end of line) characters.

Should you add/commit those changes, the next time you update your model, you should *not* see those extra lines again (because they would be already there).

So this is not an actual issue, just the way Visual Studio format that file by default. You can proceed with those changes as shown.

Comment: I got your point , but i can not commit on these changes , 
because it already on my Origin repository branch , and next time, i have to take checkout from same branch , from where i have taken now , 

these are all changes ,right now showing ,they already on my Checkout branch .

here i have tried to add a single Store Procedure ,so why ,it showing changes ,in all files . this is actually making me concern . 

if i am adding/committing these changes , my client will cancel that Pull Request and will never merge these changes , 

because these changes are not supposed to be there.

Comment: what i should do , please suggest

Comment: @Vivek Hold one, I got to go to work ;) I'll comment there shortly.

Comment: "so why ,it showing changes ,in all files": probably because you have a Visual Studio "source formatting" setting which mandates to have an empty line between methods (done on formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41533526/6309). Could be resharper too (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24861297/6309). Again, check your settings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32459206/6309

Comment: i think we are getting close to fix my issue , 

this is something should work for me ,

i will go through this one ,.



https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229830/how-to-disable-all-whitespace-autoformatting-in-visual-studio-2015/32459206#32459206

Comment: @ VonC my issue is still not fixed . i am still looking for solution to fix , i have gone above links .

Comment: @Vivek DO you mean Visual Studio is still formatting your files?

Comment: yes , can you please help me any way , i can share my screen .

Comment: @Vivek Hi Vivek. Sorry, I wasn't available more today. Basically, Git should not add extra-line by itself. So I would really double-check the formatting settings of Visual Studio. For instance: does the issue persists if you clone again the repo, and open a file with Notepad++? Does a `git status`/`git diff` shows you any file with changes *then*?

Comment: I will do  and will update you soon , i am in big trouble with this issue . 

i have re cloned once but when update from model using EF took , problem still there .

Comment: @Vivek Then the update process with EF is probably imposing this formatting. Is there any problem to add and commit with this format, and see if, going forward, only your subsequent diffs show up?

Comment: you are right , only problem with  EF is probably imposing this formatting issue , 
Once i am running EF tool then facing this problem now .

Comment: i have gone through changing many VS settings for this , but issue still  there .

Comment: @Vivek Is this code generated? (as in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613116(v=vs.113).aspx)?

Comment: yes this is exactly ,what i am using .i am using Data first technique .

Comment: @Vivek Generally, you wouldn't version (put into a Git repo) generated code, because you can re-generate locally, it after a git clone

Comment: @Vivek See if you can remove it from the Git repo (git rm --cached -r theFolderWithGeneratedfiles), comit, push, and see on a new clone if you can re-generated those files.

Comment: it means ,i need to clear my catch files  then need to do a re clone , right , i will do this same .  here " theFolderWithGeneratedfiles"  in above Command will be my Source Code folder name .

Comment: @Viv, yes, only if that folder is indeed composed of *generated* files.